# Why does this Makefile create object files with no explicit rule to compile source to object?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Why does this Makefile correctly/intelligently generate object files from source?

```
.PHONY: all, clean

OBJS=lorem.o ipsum.o

all: libfoo.so

libfoo.so: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) libfoo.so
```

```
$ make --version && make
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
cc    -c -o lorem.o lorem.c
cc    -c -o ipsum.o ipsum.c
cc -shared -o libfoo.so lorem.o ipsum.o
$
```

```
// lorem.c
int lorem() { return 42; }
```

```
// ipsum.c
int ipsum() { return 43; }
```

I haven't explicitly written any rules to compile source to object -- I've only created a rule to generate a shared library from object files.

I can surmise that there is some implicit intelligent rule baked into `make`, but I thought `make` had a reputation for being rudimentary/needing explicit rules for every level of dependency -- please help me correct this apparent misconception, and understand how/why/when `make` "intelligently" knows what to do in the absence of an explicit rule (an answer covering this specific case, but also the general case would be appreciated).

Comment: There are lots of built-in default rules for compiling files.

Comment: You can even use `make` without a makefile at all. If you type `make foo.o`, it will look for `foo.c`, `foo.cpp`, etc. going through all its default rules for creating `.o` files.

Comment: From the docs for GNU make, you can use `make -p -f/dev/null` to dump all the default builtin rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `OBJS` is `lorem.o ipsum.o`, `libfoo.so: $(OBJS)` tells `make` that `libfoo.so` depends on `lorem.o` and `ipsum.o`. So, when `make` wants to make `libfoo.so`, it wants to make `lorem.o` and `ipsum.o`.

If you do not have explicit rules that cover these, `make` considers its implicit rules. There are implicit rules to make object files from several known types of source files. So, if you have a matching source file, `make` builds the `.o` file from the corresponding source file.

You can see the implicit rules by using `-p` switch to print `make`’s database, as in `make -p -f/dev/null`. With the version I have, there is a `%.o: %.c` rule with the command `$(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<`.

The `-d` switch will tell `make` to print debugging information, showing in excessive detail what rules it considers and finds when making specific targets.